# Create table as in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I do have a basic question. I have changed from PLSQL to SQL Server lately and I am struggling with basic task such is CREATE TABLE.

In PLSQL is normal to write

```
 create table TIRED_LIKE_DOG as select * database;
```

How can I create table in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio?

Is it really that I first need to create table like

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.COSTUME
(
    text CHAR(5), -- need commas
    Price4 DECIMAL(12,2), 
    Price2 DECIMAL(12,2),
    price  DECIMAL(12,2), -- Number isn't a valid SQL        Server data type  
    Category_ID CHAR(5)
 );
```

and then I have to select in some table?

Thank you.

Have a nice day

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To create a new table from the old one

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE2 FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 3):

you can simply create as:

```
select * into <new_table> from <old_table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you got the Management Studio you can simple right click on your database and select new table. If you need it code based, try this simple solution:

```
CREATE TABLE COSTUME  
([ID] int PRIMARY KEY,  
[Text] char(5) NOT NULL,  
[Price4] decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,  
[Price2] decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,  
[Price] decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,  
[Category_ID] CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
)
```

I created a extra column "ID" because I dont know if your "Category_ID" is a primary Key. 
I also didn't allow your columns to be empty, that is the "Not Null" after every new Column. You can also change that by simply removing that statement.

Hopefully that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select N.* into <new_table> from (Select ...) As N
```

old table this seems to work with me just fine